# NetSuite: Create button to send PDF of Invoice using SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

- Create a Button on Invoice called SEND EMAIL using SuiteScript. Only show this button to View Mode and when User is Administrator.
- If user click that button, it should send an email with Invoice PDF Attachment.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in workflow :

1. Create a **Workflow** against **Transactions**, subtype **Invoices**. Check the **On Create** and **On View Or Update** checkboxes.
2. Change the name of the first state to "Start".
3. In the "Start" state, add a button, call it "SEND EMAIL", set the **Trigger On** field to **View**. Add a condition of **User Role** Is **Administrator**.
4. Create a second state, call it "Do Send".
5. Add a transition from "Start" to "Do Send". Change the **Execute On Button** field and choose "SEND EMAIL".
6. Add a **Send Email** action to the "Do Send" state. Configure the action parameters (sender, recipient, body, subject, etc). Check the **Include Transaction** checkbox and select your preferred format (PDF/HTML/etc).

Comment: No, only using SuiteScript.